# How to do slide show in wpf. Changing windows content like slide show

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I want to display window and when user will click a button then **show for him next content in the same window**. And I want also to do a animation. Is it possible? Animation is not important. **I only want to change content dynamicaly**. I cant find it anywhere...

Please give me simplier solution for this without any frameworks.

Content is not only images. There will be many controls.

I'm using **WPF** with .NET Framework 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to approach this without a lot of overhead would be to prepare all slides of the slideshow as UserControls, let the main window have a

```xml
<ContentPresenter x:Name="CurrentSlidePresenter" />
```

and use

```csh
UserControl currentSlide = GetCurrentSlide(); // implement this to your liking
CurrentSlidePresenter.Content = currentSlide;
```

in the button click handler.

This approach can be expanded to use animation using [FluidKit](http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to just load content from xaml in your project with XamlReader class.

Here is  a link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashish/archive/2007/08/14/dynamically-loading-xaml.aspx

Simplified code from the link:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadXAMLMethod(); 
        }


        public void LoadXAMLMethod()
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader mysr = new StreamReader("Page1.xaml");
                DependencyObject rootObject = XamlReader.Load(mysr.BaseStream) as DependencyObject;

                this.Content = rootObject;
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Evading more reliable approaches, such as using MVVM is not a good thing. You should consider at some point to get acquainted with MVVM, if you are to solve such UI-manipulation tasks often.

Answer (score 0):

in short, you will have to StoryBoard and Trigger Animation technologies in WPF. Google for "WPF Window Sliding Animation Example".

[Found this useful](http://www.wearerighteous.com/programming/wpf-effects-animation-roundup-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for http://transitionals.codeplex.com/ ?

*"Transitionals is a framework for building and using WPF transitions which provide an easy way to switch between UI views in a rich and animated way."*